# Obtaining the Maximum value from a table field and parsing same as a parameter to that column for subtraction by all records of the same column

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need to  fetch the Maximum value from a table column and parse same (i.e. this maximum value as a parameter) to  the same column  for subtraction in an added (new) column (called difference):

Example:

```
    Month_number 
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    5 
    5
    6
```

I need to take the Maximum value "9" of the month_number field and use this(9) a parameter to subtract each record of the same column to then get a new column called "difference" like this:

```
    Difference
    4
    3
    2
    1
    0
    4
    4
    3
```

Comment: It would help if you had an example and a specific question.

Comment: Why not just add a custom column?

Comment: I'm really sorry. I have provided an example to better explain the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a step where you determine the minimum for example

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblInp"]}[Content],
    min = List.Min(Source[Nr]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Nr", Int64.Type}}),
    Diff = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Diff", each [Nr]-min)
in
    Diff
```